# Is there a way to writing staticmethods to python classes outside of the classes without extending the class?

Tags: python

I would like to this in the use case of which I can keep my DB schema (of which are declared via classes) in SQLAlchemy. At the same time, I would like to various staticmethods or util methods to these objects. But I would like to keep the schema clean and just be schema. Is there a way of writing these additional methods that would allow me to declare methods outside the scope of the class? Thanks.

Comment: technically, i can write an external library to interface with the objects too. but i'd like to know if theres a way of achieving the above? also, what are your thoughts of the "pythonic" way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (`lol()` is a static "injected" method)?

```
class Foo (object):
    pass

Foo.lol = staticmethod (lambda: 1)
print Foo.lol ()
```

Your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: Your answer matches the way I interpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

As staticmethods in Python are nothing else than simple functions bound to a class, you can easily do it like this:

```
def pseudoStaticMethod ():
    return 'It works.'

class A:
    def __init__ ( self ):
        print( 'A.__init__:', pseudoStaticMethod() )

class B:
    def __init__ ( self ):
        print( 'B.__init__:', pseudoStaticMethod() )
```

Or if you really want to assign them to the class/object:

```
def pseudoStaticMethod ():
    return 'It works.'

class A:
    myStaticMethod = staticmethod( pseudoStaticMethod )
    def __init__ ( self ):
        print( 'A.__init__:', self.myStaticMethod() )

class B:
    myStaticMethod = staticmethod( pseudoStaticMethod )
    def __init__ ( self ):
        print( 'B.__init__:', self.myStaticMethod() )
```

Or you can even make use of the fact that Python supports multiple inheritance:

```
class BaseClassWithAStaticMethod:
    @staticmethod
    def myStaticMethod ():
        return 'It works.'

class A ( BaseClassWithAStaticMethod ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        print( 'A.__init__:', self.myStaticMethod() )

class B ( BaseClassWithAStaticMethod ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        print( 'B.__init__:', self.myStaticMethod() )
```